# LuaJIT / script loading failed with long function name

Tags: c++, lua, luajit

I have some Lua scripts which is running in C++ without any error.
I'd like to change to LuaJIT 2.0.5
I found an error during loading script and that is very weird
It seems to depend on function name length 
see below

[testing environment]
- Visual Studio 2015 on windowns 10(C++)
- LuaJIT 2.0.5 built with VS2015
- script build command : luajit.exe -b util.lua util.lua.luajit
- sol v2.20.2 (revision d67c5b7)(https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library
- sol code : https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2

[Question]
Is there any variable length limit or function name ?
this script runs well with Lua 5.3.4
ONLY **1 difference** in function name length.

```
-- failed
function check_inventory_craft(goal_tabl, my_record_table, playerobject)
end
-- error message : [sol2] An error occurred and has been passed to an error handler: sol: syntax error: (binary): cannot load malformed bytecode

-- success
function check_inventorycraft(goal_tabl, my_record_table, playerobject)
end
```

Comment: I found that 20 length of function name could make an error, 21 function name length does not make an error.. could it be a luajit bug ?   I feel I should exame luajit code.

Comment: `function do_some_stuff_but_with_a_very_long_name() end` works fine for me on LuaJIT 2.1.0; from the error message it seems like you're using [sol2](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2), maybe that's causing the problem?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer can you use function name what it's length is 20(exactly) ? like `function f23456789_1234567890() end`